# Reference a nested enum in a dictionary?

Tags: class, swift, enums, nested

Doesn't seem like Swift allows nested enums to be referenced from a dictionary. I could simply move the enum out of the class and that would solve the problem, but I need to create another enum names Status under another class. So it needs to be a nested enum

```
class User {

    enum Status: String {
        case Alive = "alive"
        case Dead = "dead"
    }
}

var userStatuses = [User.Status: String]()
```

Comment: This is a bug in Swift, reported it to apple

Comment: I agree this is a bug, especially since the long-hand version works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the non-shorthand version.

```
var statuses = Dictionary<User.Status, String>()
```

It looks like a bug when using the shorthand version `[User.Status: String]()` but the non-shorthand version appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use a `typealias`:

```
class User {
    enum Status: String {
        case Alive = "alive"
        case Dead = "dead"
    }
}

typealias Key = User.Status

var myDictionary = [Key: String]()
myDictionary[.Alive] = "something"

println(myDictionary[.Alive]!) // prints "something"
```

Comment: Hmmm seems like a bug in swift

Comment: Yeah, I don't find it very elegant either.